# golang Dynamic Type Conversion

Tags: go

From a snippet (not comprehensively functional here):

```
type SomeType struct {
    UserEmail   sql.NullString    `db:"user_email"`
    RecID       sql.NullInt64     `db:"rec_id"`
}

for g := 0; g < s.NumField(); g++ {
   f := s.Field(g)
   tType = f.Type().String()

   tType = strings.Replace(tType, `sql.Null`, ``, 1)
   tType = strings.Replace(tType, `mysql.Null`, ``, 1)
   tType = strings.Replace(tType, `decimal.NullDecimal`, `Decimal`, 1)
   tType = strings.Replace(tType, `myTime`, `Time`, 1)

   fmt.Println(g, typeOfT.Field(g).Name, tType, f)
}
```

For normal output, I write UserEmail.String. If the .String is absent, then the output is:

```
   UserEmail String {johndoe@somecompany.com true}
```

How would I dynamically append the .String, or .Int64, depending on the data type, wherein that type extention actually functions to produce:

```
   UserEmail String johndoe@somecompany.com
```

Essentially turning the strings "UserEmail" and "String" into UserEmail.String

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `s` is reflect.Value of an instance of `SomeType`, `s.Field(g).Field(0).Interface()` returns the value of the first (0th) field of those NullXxx struct types. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/y4LFn2KJko3

Comment: Usually I'd expect to see code more directly unmarshal into `SomeType`, and not use reflection at all.  Can you show a little bit more of the code; in particular where `s` comes from and how it relates to `SomeType`?

Comment: mkopriva, ... .Field(0).Interface() worked nice! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. If you post it, I'll mark it as answered.